# grep used to find a table of floating point numbers

Tags: regex, grep

I have some analysis code on a computing cluster.  The output of the code is a table of floating point numbers.  The final output is printed to standard out, with a bunch of other messages preceding it and following it.  It looks something like this:

```
Welcome to Computer X
Setting up parallel environment...
Setup complete.  Running tasks....
0.059 9.342114 10.324921 0.3 0
0.123 123.4231102 231.49 45.7 84
Job completed on July 4, 1776
Thank you and have a nice day
```

I need to extract the numbers only.  Unfortunately, I don't know a priori how many digits will comprise each number (is it going to be 0.342123 or 1 or 1.05), and how many of the text lines will precede or follow the number.

I have used grep before, but I don't know much of anything about regular expressions.  I looked up examples for, say, how to match phone numbers (###-###-####) etc., but I couldn't think of anything where you don't know how many digits to skip.  The only thing I do know is that there will be, say, 5 columns of data to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -ho` with regex pattern

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?(\s+|$))+$
```

or if you sure 5 numbers are always in row, then

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?(\s+|$)){5}$
```

Comment: What's the full grep command that includes this expression?  Just want to make sure I get it right.

Comment: @Joe - Use `grep -ho '^(\d+(\.\d+)?(\s+|$)){5}$' fileName` or `otherApp | grep -ho '^(\d+(\.\d+)?(\s+|$)){5}$'`

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work.  I'm using Cygwin if that matters.  Also, doesn't the ^ symbol in the beginning mean "the opposite of" the string?  May be a stupid question.

Comment: @Joe - check your `grep --h` options

Comment: That was helpful.  It seems like grep -h "^[0-9]" filename works, if you assume that every line that starts with a number is a data line.  I can't get the other version to work though, even though it seems like your version is much more precise.